# Dependence of refractive index on surroundings

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics

Is there any equation which relates the refractive index of a medium's value with its surrounding's refractive index?

Answer (score 3):

Refractive index does not depend upon the surrounding mediums refractive index. It does depend on external factors such as pressure and heat however.